# Calculate period between two dates in months and days

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am currently using the following code to determine the period between two dates in months and days:

```
DECLARE @date1 DATETIME = '2009-01-01 00:00:00'
DECLARE @date2 DATETIME = '2010-06-30 00:00:00'

SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(mm, @date1, @date2) AS VARCHAR(6)) + ' Months ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(dd, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, @date1, @date2), @date1), @date2) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' Days'
```

The issue with this is that the code doesn't seem to count the last day, so the above returns 17 months 29 days whereas the return I need is 18 months.

Likewise the following:

```
DECLARE @date1 DATETIME = '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
DECLARE @date2 DATETIME = '2020-01-31 00:00:00'

SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(mm, @date1, @date2) AS VARCHAR(6)) + ' Months ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(dd, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, @date1, @date2), @date1), @date2) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' Days'
```

returns 0 months 30 days instead of one month.

Is there a way to amend the above to recognise whole months where the number of days is equal to a month and also count the final day?

Thanks

Comment: Ask a friend: "What day is one month later than 1 Jan 2020?" Chances are, they will say 1 Feb 2020. If you want the difference to include both the starting and the ending date, add 1.

Comment: To illustrate George's point, try to set the second date to the very last millisecond of the month :)
` DECLARE @date1 DATETIME = '2020-01-01 00:00:00' `
` DECLARE @date2 DATETIME = dateadd(dd,0,'2020-01-31 23:59:59.999') `
` SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(mm, @date1, @date2) AS VARCHAR(6)) + ' Months ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(dd, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, @date1, @date2), @date1), @date2) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' Days'  `

Comment: You are getting correct results - it's your expectations that are strange - the difference between January's 31th and January's 1st is not a month but 30 days - it would be a month if you would measure February's 1st and January's 1st.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add one day (using `DATEADD`) to the second date (`@date2`):

```
-- first example
DECLARE @date1 DATETIME = '2009-01-01 00:00:00'
DECLARE @date2 DATETIME = '2010-06-30 00:00:00'

SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(mm, @date1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @date2)) AS VARCHAR(6)) + ' Months ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(dd, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, @date1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @date2)), @date1), DATEADD(DAY, 1, @date2)) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' Days'

-- second example
DECLARE @date1 DATETIME = '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
DECLARE @date2 DATETIME = '2020-01-31 00:00:00'

SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(mm, @date1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @date2)) AS VARCHAR(6)) + ' Months ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(dd, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, @date1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @date2)), @date1), DATEADD(DAY, 1, @date2)) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' Days'
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d43ffaefd461574757bcd1fd726b28af)

Have a look at the following examples:

- `DATEDIFF` of `2020-01-01` and `2020-01-01` is 0.
  *(max. difference between `2020-01-01 00:00:00` and `2020-01-01 23:59:59` is equals to 0 day, 23 hours, 59 minutes and 59 seconds.*
- `DATEDIFF` of `2020-01-01` and `2020-01-02` is 1.
  *(max. difference between `2020-01-01 00:00:00` and `2020-01-02 23:59:59` is equals to 1 day, 23 hours, 59 minutes and 59 seconds.*

So you can't count the last day as day in the difference since the day isn't over.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense to me now. Much appreciated.